# Scala Sort List[(String, Double)]

Tags: list, scala, sorting

I'm trying to sort a List[(String, Double)] by first the Double and then the String, in Scala. Meaning I want the List by be sorted first by the size of the Double and then the Strings in alphabetical order.

For example,

```
val sortThisList = List[("C", 2.0), ("B", 1.0), ("A", 1.0), ("B", 2.0), ("A", 2.0), ("C", 1.0)]
```

sortThisList sorted should then look like:

```
List[("A", 2.0), ("B", 2.0), ("C", 2.0), ("A", 1.0), ("B", 1.0), ("C", 1.0)]
```

I have tried using the sortBy function:

```
val sortedList = sortThisList.sortBy(_._2).sortBy(_._1)
```

This is the only version of what I have tried with both sortBy and sortWith that has compiled. However, it only results in a version of sortedList that is sorted in alphabetical order instead of by the size of the Double and then by alphabetical order.

Comment: What have you tried? Why it didn't work? Have you at least looked to the [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/)?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. When I try your code, I get "wrong number of type parameters for method apply: [A](elems: A*): List[A] in trait IterableFactory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, but you need to sort in the opposite order and negate the double to order high to low:

```
sortThisList.sortBy(_._1).sortBy(-_._2)
```

This works because Scala sort is **stable** which means that values stay in the same order if the sort values are the same. So the first `sortBy` ensures that the strings are ordered and the second `sortBy` sorts by the doubles (in reverse). If there is more than one record with the same double value, they remain sorted by string value.

However this can be done in a single operation using `sortBy`:

```
sortThisList.sortBy(e => (-e._2, e._1))
```

This works by extracting the fields in order of priority and the sorting by that value.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is caused by a typo:

> ```scala
> val sortThisList = List[("C", 2.0), ("B", 1.0), ("A", 1.0), ("B", 2.0), ("A", 2.0), ("C", 1.0)]
> ```

This won't work. What you are doing is passing six *type arguments* which are pairs of literal types. You probably want to pass *value arguments*. In Scala, like in almost every programming language (yes, I know, there is Rebol), value arguments are passed in round parentheses, not square brackets.

Comment: You are incorrect about the effect of two sorts. Scala sort is stable, so any sorting done on the first sort is retained for records where the second sort value is the same. So one answer to the problem is `sortThisList.sortBy(_._1).sortBy(_._2)` (as I explain in my answer).

Comment: The also does not produce the correct answer because the `Double` values should be sorted high to low, not low to high.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out.

```
val listByValue = sortThisList.groupBy { case (key, value) => value }.toSeq
val listByValue = listByValue.sortBy { case (value, group) => value }
val sortedList = listByValue.flatMap { case (key, value) => value.sortBy { case (key, value) => value } }.reverse.toList
```

Comment: Your solution, as posted, does not compile.